# Asp.net identity Google account id migration from openId to oauth

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, google-oauth, asp.net-identity, google-openid

I have an existing asp.net mvc5 application using DotNetOpenAuth for Google OpenId authentication.
I am migrating to Asp.Net Identity, and using Google+ Auth with OAuth2.0.

But I have seen thant I can't map existing OpenId account Id to OAuth2.0 Id :
  - Old id is : https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=blablabla
  - New Id is : a long number

Since I would like to use new id, I am searching for help on migrating identities.
I have not found yet a simple sample to achieve this.

I am using a new asp.net mvc5 application (freshly scaffolded), added Microsoft Identity (with custom implementation for my data), configured the GoogleOAuth2 provider.

When I try to login, surprise ! :) Account id have changed...

I have read some posts that tell to add "openid.realm" to auth request but, how can I change the authentication request url, and how do I know the value to put in it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To change the authentication request to include the `openid.real`m parameter, you can use the OnApplyRedirect delegate e.g.

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "",
    ClientSecret = "",
    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnApplyRedirect = context =>
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "openid.realm", "http://mywebsite.com/openid/realm" }
            };
            var redirectUri = WebUtilities.AddQueryString(context.RedirectUri, dictionary);
            context.Response.Redirect(redirectUri);
        },
    }
});
```

The value of `openid.realm` needs to be the [realm](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#realms) you used for OpenID 2.0

The [google migration doc](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#map-identifiers) has information on how to map from the users old id to the new one

Comment: Adding the openid.realm works (when I put a bad value I got an error), but by reading the doc, I don't know where I can find the "openid_id" field.
If I understand well, the value can be retrieved when querying the access token. But the code that does this has either no entry point or events that can be handled...

Comment: In the documentation, the step 3 tells that the response of the token request contains the "openid_id" field needed for me. This is not the case.
Ay idea ?

Comment: I think a lot of people have had problems retrieving the openid_id. It could be a bug.

Comment: I can't retrieve it either. The data just isn't returned by Google.

Comment: This gets partway. Inside Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google, after posting to the Google token endpoint, the openid_id field is encoded inside the id_token which sits next to the access_token. A JwtSecurityToken object can be used to decode. Unfortunately, the id_token value is dropped and does not pass through to the OnAuthenticated handler. There does not seem to be a way to get at the openid_id. Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect looks promising (I see a JWT lurking inside) but the Google part seems to be a work in progress. Either way it will take some work from the Katana team to resolve.

Comment: Finally got Google to return the token_id by doing a string replace on the context.RedirectUri to add the id_token parameter to response_type but Google returns a malformed query string in the form of https://mydomain/signin-google#state... instead of https://mydomain/signin-google?state... The id_token is there now though.